# Import customer register information from PHP site into Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: php, dynamics-crm-2011

I spend a lot of time and searching and i don't find any solution for connect to my company crm and inser register customers information into the contact list crm.
my site backend is php.
Is there a solution for conncet to Dedicated crm company and insert my costomer info such as name and phone , ... to contact list of it?

Comment: Have you tried any code ? you could write your own `WebService` in .net, that would be called from your `PHP Site` and the `.net WebService` will insert data in `CRM`.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store these contacts information at the moment? If the answer is database then I would suggest using ssis in combination of CRM web services. 
[link](http://thecrmclub.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-integrate-dynamics-crm-ssis.html?m=1)

You can get the guid from inserted record back in to your source database so next time you run the package it knows if the record is new or already exist.